# Understanding Segmentation Faults with a custom linker script for a simple 'Hello World' - section names or base address below 64k

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, ld, linker-scripts

Basic Hello World as seen many times before on x86_64 Linux:

```
global my_start_symbol 

section .text

my_start_symbol:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1 
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, msg_len
        syscall 

        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall

section .rodata:
msg: db "Hello, world!", 10 
msg_len: equ $ - msg
```

My working `ld` linker script:

```
ENTRY(my_start_symbol)
SECTIONS 
{
  . = 0x10000;
  .text : { *(.text*) }
  .rodata : { *(.rodata*) }
}
```

Invoked with:

```
nasm -f elf64 assembly.asm -o assembly.o
ld -T linker.ld assembly.o -o assembly
```

I get various segmentation faults when I experiment with the following changes:

1. If I remove the `. = 0x10000` inside of my linker script or make it anything less than `0x10000` I get a segfault. I thought this may be due to page size, however `getconf PAGE_SIZE` returns 4K, so I don't know why 8K is necessary.
2. If I change the `.text` section in my assembly file to say `.my_section_name` and update the linker to say  `.my_section_name : { *(.my_section_name*) }` I get a segfault. I thought the section names like `.text`, `.data` etc. were by convention, and that you could make them anything you wanted. If I'm wrong, why would `.text : { *(.my_section_name*) }` give a segfault also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `0x10000` minimum is probably due to the default setting of `vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536` (https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr), preventing user-space from mapping any low-address pages to make sure that NULL-deref faults noisily, even for code like `ptr[i]` with some medium-sized index.

A few names like `.text` are special (for NASM and/or ld), and have a default set of permissions (in this case read + exec).  Some random name is probably read + write without exec.  Check with `readelf -a a.out`, epsecially the Program Headers (which govern how an executable is mapped into memory by the kernel).

Also probably interesting to have a look at `readelf -a hello.o` to check the section headers in the NASM output.

Comment: How would you set the section to executable? I tried explicitly assigning the section to a executable memory region, e.g: `MEMORY { rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 512K}`. `readelf -a` shows it not as executable still.

Comment: @RyanMcClue: IDK, I've never had to mess with linker scripts myself.  If your google doesn't turn up the answer for you, (e.g. terms like `site:stackoverflow.com linker script link section into executable segment`) ask a new question.