# How to make a custom section executable (other than .text)

Tags: linux, x86-64, nasm, ld, linker-scripts

Basic Hello World as seen many times before on x86_64 Linux:

```
global my_start_symbol 

section .my_section

my_start_symbol:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1 
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, msg_len
        syscall 

        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall

section .rodata:
msg: db "Hello, world!", 10 
msg_len: equ $ - msg
```

My current `ld` linker script:

```
__linux_mmap_min_addr = 0x10000;

ENTRY(my_start_symbol)

MEMORY
{
  rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 512K
}

SECTIONS 
{
  . = __linux_mmap_min_addr;
  .my_section : 
  { 
    *(.my_section*) 
  } > rom
  .rodata : 
  {
    *(.rodata*) 
  } > rom
}
```

Invoked with:

```
nasm -f elf64 assembly.asm -o assembly.o
ld -T linker.ld assembly.o -o assembly
```

I'm currently getting a segfault. Inspecting the output of `readelf -a` I can see that `my_section` does not have executable permissions. I believe this is causing the segfault. If I replace it with `.text : { *(.my_section*) } > rom` it still does not get set as executable. Only if I revert to using `.text` everywhere as is convention, does it set it as executable.

Comment: It might be sufficient (or necessary?) to use NASM to set the section as executable, e.g. `section .my_section exec` (https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.2).  I would have thought that setting permissions in a linker script would override that, assuming that's the right linker-script syntax, but IDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assessments (at least on x86_64 Linux with NASM):

1. The flags set in `ld` `MEMORY` definition are irrelevant in setting the section to executable. The [NASM ELF Section extensions](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.2) are what matter, i.e. `section .my_section exec` will work even if `MEMORY` does not have `x` flag (thanks to @peter-cordes).
2. If you have specific `ld` `MEMORY` definitions that you are using, the origin cannot be `0`, but must be at least `0x10000` (see this [S.O q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926989/understanding-segmentation-faults-with-a-custom-linker-script-for-a-simple-hell) for more info) Using `. = 0x10000;` at the start of the section is not sufficient.